# Show using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit that $\lim_{x\to 1} -x^4 = -1$ and find the value of $\delta$.

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I've been asked to show using $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of limit that $$\lim_{x\to 1} -x^4 = -1$$
To do so I've been asked that what is the value of $\delta$ would be from one of these two options :

a) $\min \{1,\frac{\epsilon}{15}\}$

b) $\frac{\epsilon}{15}$

I'm really confused as there's no other information given. And there's no way for me to ask for any more information.

What I have done so far is :

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given, then

$$ \mid -x^4 - (-1) \mid \\
  = \mid x^4 -1 \mid \\
  = |x-1||x+1||x^2+1| \lt \epsilon \\ \implies |x-1| < \frac{\epsilon}{|x+1||x^2+1|}
 $$

Now since the domain of the function is not given here and even though I know that $x\to 1$ but I am not being able to "generally" deduce the maximum value of the expression $\frac{1}{|x+1||x^2+1|}$. This is where I'm stuck.

Can anyone please help?? It's really urgent. Thank you.

Comment: You can read what I wrote here. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4031694/399263 Basically prefer using $|u|=|x-1|<\varepsilon$ and then $|u|^n\le|u|\le 1$ for all $n$ for the bounded part, all comes more naturally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}|-x^4-(-1)|&=|x^4-1|\\&=|x-1|\times|x^3+x^2+x+1|.\end{align}And, if $|x-1|<1$, then$$|x|=|(x-1)+1|\leqslant|x-1|+1<2,$$and therefore$$|x^3+x^2+x+1|\leqslant2^3+2^2+2+1=15,$$which implies that $|-x^4-(-1)|<15|x-1|$. So, if $|x-1|<\frac\varepsilon{15}$, then $|-x^4-(-1)|<\varepsilon$. In particular, $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon{15}\right\}$ will work.

Comment: I just have one question. If I just show the case $|x|<1$ then is this a complete answer? I mean if you were to check my answer analytically, does my answer cover everything?

Comment: No, since $|x|<1$ does not imply that $|-x^4-(-1)|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: I think I was not clear. I meant the way you showed that when $|x|<1$ then $\delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{15}\}$ will work, does this cover everything?

Comment: Yes, it covers everything.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: Yes. I made an error and I've edited my answer.

Comment: I just have one more question. You wrote that when "$|x|<1$ then ... ". But for the definition of limit of this function we need $\delta$ such that $|x-1|< \delta$. So in case when $|x|<1$ how the $ \delta = \min\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{15}\}$ work ? I mean $|x| < 1$ doesn't necessarily imply that $|x-1|<1$. So wouldn't that be the case of "If $|x-1| < 1$ then, $x < 2$ and this implies $|x^3+x^2+x+1|<15$ so $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac\varepsilon{15}\right\}$ works"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132417/discussion-between-jose-carlos-santos-and-itachi).